# How to add a new empty field or delimiter in a text file before to be read by a OPENROWSET?

Tags: sql-server, excel, powershell, excel-formula, etl

I have inherited one ETL process and one of the new aims is try to get all the data from a text file and insert it into a SQL Server Instance. The problem is that the new format of the text file changed and my stored procedure does not work anymore so I trying to change the format of the txt file to fit to my SP.

First of all I was able to delete some data with this powershell script

```
$newdata=foreach($line in get-content "C:\users\user12\text_file1.txt")
{
   $line -replace 'text to delete1',' '

}
else
{
   $line

}

$newdata+=$newdata1


$newdata1=foreach($line in $newdata)
{
   $line -replace 'text to delete2',' '

}
else
{
   $line

}

$newdata1 | set-content "C:\users\user12\text_file1.txt" -force
$newdata1 | set-contect "C:\users\user12\text_file1.txt" -WorksheetName "datachanged" -AutoSize
```

The challenge begins when I exported to excel

Here a pseudo-example about how looks the excel and what I expect

How actual looks

| Time | Action | User | Size | Data | Folder | SO | Direction | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10:00 PM | Delete | Admin | 3KB | PDF | /pdf/system_data.pdf | WO | 10.0.0.0 | 14 |
| 10:30 PM | Created | Admin | 5KB | XLSX | UB | 10.1.0.0 | 12 |  |
| 10:45 PM | Sent | User | 8KB | CSV | /pdf/system_data1.csv | WO | 10.0.1.0 | 07 |
| 10:30 PM | Created | Admin | 12KB | XLSX | UB | 10.1.0.0 | 12 |  |

What I expect

| Time | Action | User | Size | Data | Folder | SO | Direction | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10:00 PM | Delete | Admin | 3KB | PDF | /pdf/system_data.pdf | WO | 10.0.0.0 | 14 |
| 10:30 PM | Created | Admin | 5KB | XLSX |  | UB | 10.1.0.0 | 12 |
| 10:45 PM | Sent | User | 8KB | CSV | /pdf/system_data1.csv | WO | 10.0.1.0 | 07 |
| 10:30 PM | Created | Admin | 12KB | XLSX |  | UB | 10.1.0.0 | 12 |

I need to create an empty field or move to the right side all the values from "folder" to be able to read the file correctly with an OPENROWSET function and insert into a table.

Comment: There's no such thing as "foreach/else" - but the good news is that you don't need it anyway. `-replace` will already return `$line` as-is if the pattern doesn't match

Comment: so you want to find lines without 9 fields and assume that the Folder field is the one that is missing? hard to do that without converting from CSV

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data is tab-delimited, and that you with to insert an extra tab in lines containing exactly 8 fields (7 tabs), the following may work.

```
$Header = "Time", "Action", "User", "Size", "Data", "Folder", "SO", "Direction", "Age"
$Content = `
"10:00 PM`tDelete`tAdmin`t3KB`tPDF`t/pdf/system_data.pdf`tWO`t10.0.0.0`t14",
"10:30 PM`tCreated`tAdmin`t5KB`tXLSX`tUB`t10.1.0.0`t12",
"10:45 PM`tSent`tUser`t8KB`tCSV`t/pdf/system_data1.csv`tWO`t10.0.1.0`t07",
"10:30 PM`tCreated`tAdmin`t12KB`tXLSX`tUB`t10.1.0.0`t12"

$Content | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -Header $Header | Format-Table

$match = '^([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)$'
$replace = '$1\t$2\t$3\t$4\t$5\t\t$6\t$7\t$8' -replace '\\t',"`t"  # Is there a better way to code this?
$Content = $Content | foreach { $_ -replace $match,$replace }

$Content | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -Header $Header | Format-Table
```

The match string matches an alternating sequence of non-tab characters and tabs, capturing the text between the tabs. The replace string just rebuilds the line with the extra tab. (I couldn't figure out how to include tabs and replacement strings in the same powershell string literal, so I had to actually do a -replace on the replace string.)

Caution: The above may not properly handle quoted values that themselves contain delimiters.

Comment: Great
I'm going to test it and see how works in a real case

Comment: Sadly I forgot to mention that the text file I receive has hundreds or thousands of rows
So would be impossible to me if I have to type manually all the data in a variable similar to ($Content) 
Also I have a question about variable $Header, because is already in the text file, for example 200 rows and the first row is the header and then a space betweet the neext 200 rows with the same header as first row
So in this case would be double header?

Comment: The inlining of $Content and $Header data and the code to format data for display were for demonstration purposes only. The core of the suggested answer was in the three lines: `$match = ...`, `$replace = ...` and `... -replace $match,$replace ...`. It is presumed that you would adapt the logic to your specific needs.